# CodeRush Xpress with JustCode on VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, coderush-xpress, justcode

Does CodeRush Xpress play nicely with JustCode on VS 2010?

Will the default key bindings clash?

Background: I am inexperienced with C# and would like the IDE to help me as much as possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We (DevExpress) were not told about incompatibilities with JustCode. So, most likely they will work fine. If you see any issues we will be happy to research and resolve them - just drop a line at support@devexpress.com.

Comment: Please let us know how it goes. Contact us at support@devexpress.com or via twitter by mentioning "CodeRush" in your tweet.

Answer (score 0):

I am with Telerik, and I've experienced no problems testing JustCode with CodeRush Xpress. It may be possible that installing additional Visual Studio extensions will overwrite the key mappings for JustCode. If you suspect this has occurred, go to JustCode | Options | General and click "Reset keyboard shortcuts".

Comment: Thank you. JustCode is great. I'd already found and used the reset.